# 3D Median box filter on the 4-th dimension of a point cloud (Python)

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, median, point-clouds

I'm looking for an efficient way to compute a moving 3D median filter of size m*n*p on **the 4th dimension** "U" of a large 3D point cloud (x,y,z). This differs from typical filter for Nd images in two ways: (1) there can be several values in each image voxel (several points falling in that voxels) and (2) Some voxels can be empty, and should be replaced by the median in the box around them.

I have converged to the following method, which however seems not so efficient when the number of points increases (while it performs better for increasing box averaging windows) ...

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import time 
import sys

npts=10**5 # Number of points in the cloud
L=100 # Dimension of the domain (grid)
filt_size=[1,1,1] # extent of the median filter on each size of the grid voxel

# Generate random points and scalar u
x=np.random.random(npts)*L
y=np.random.random(npts)*L
z=np.random.random(npts)*L
u=np.random.random(npts)

# Initiate time clock
t0=time.clock()

# Take grid position of points 
x=np.uint32(np.round(x))
y=np.uint32(np.round(y))
z=np.uint32(np.round(z))

# Index point in a flatten way
index=x*L*L+y*L+z
idmax=np.max(index) # Maximum for latter use
idsort=np.argsort(index) # Sort indexes to be quicker ?
index=index[idsort]
u=np.float16(u[idsort])
# Group by grid pixel (unique indexes given by udi and their extent by ui)
idu,ui=np.unique(index,return_index=True)

# Neighboor indexes of the index 0
neighboors=np.array([i*L*L+j*L+k for i, j,k in itertools.product(range(-filt_size[0],filt_size[0]+1), range(-filt_size[1],filt_size[1]+1),range(-filt_size[2],filt_size[2]+1))],dtype='int32')

# Make L^3 list of empty arrays in which we will aggregate all points in the neighboorood of a voxel
U=[np.array([],dtype='float16')]*int((L+1)*(L+1)*(L+1))
for i in range(len(idu)-1):
    ul=u[ui[i]:ui[i+1]] # the scalar data of voxel idu[i]
    neigh=neighboors+idu[i] # Neighbooring cells TO where the scalar data should be copied
    for k in neigh[(neigh>=0)&(neigh<=idmax)]: # Take only neighboors in the grid domain 
        U[k]=np.concatenate((ul,U[k])) # stack with existent data
        U[k].sort(axis=0) # sort
    sys.stdout.write('\r progress {:d}%'.format(i*100/len(idu)))
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Finally, gather the median by taking the middle element of each array
# empty voxels are filled by nan
Umed=np.zeros((L+1)**3,dtype='float16')+np.nan
for i in range(len(U)):
    if U[i].shape[0]>0: # Check if not-empty
        Umed[i]=U[i][np.round(U[i].shape[0]/2)]
    sys.stdout.write('\r progress {:d}%'.format(i*100/len(U)))
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Reshape Umed in a (L+1)*(L+1)*(L+1) array
Umed=Umed.reshape((L+1,L+1,L+1))

print 'Elapsed :',time.clock()-t0
```

The time statistics are the following :

```
filt_size       10^5 points     10^6 points     10^7 points
[1,1,1]         10.89 s         40.09 s         137.97
[2,1,1]         13.64 s         68.46 s         x
[3,1,1]         16.67 s         94.10 s         x
[2,2,2]         25.57 s         207.75 s
```

Some ideas to improve the methods ?
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not so sure what the 4-th dimension of a 3D point cloud is? And why don't you make a histogram first of the point cloud and apply the median filter then?

Comment: By 4th dimension, I mean any scalar data that is coming with the 3D point (x,y,z).  What I need is an image (a map of this data) on a 3D grid, with the voxel component being the 4th dimension, on which we have applied a median box filter of a given size, thus taking into account the points in adjacent voxels. Making an histogram for each voxel might be a better idea indeed, then updating iteratively it neighboor point values. I'll post that soon.